# Htaccess Modify String then Redirect 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the following into htaccess using - redirect 301

redirect "mysite.com/longname/{20 character string}" to "mysite.com/shortname/{10 character string}"

basically to redirect the "longname" to "shortname" and cut the "20 character string" to the first 10 characters

so when I go to mywebsite.com/longname/aaaaabbbbbcccccddddd,
it rewrites it into mywebsite.com/shortname/aaaaabbbbb

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /longname/(.*) /shortname/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What you have already looks valid enough. You might need to lose the initial slash before `longname` but otherwise it looks right.

Comment: Thanks Max! Your advice, plus the answer below, did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to limit the input using a regular expression such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /longname/(.{0,10}) /shortname/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will match a string of 0-10 characters following /longname/.

Comment: Thanks.
Your code worked, minus the initial slash before "longname" (thanks Max S.)